# Clicking link within a HTML List

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying use Excel's IE automation tools to click a website link within a users profile of this site. Using the following in VBA:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("website")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

But keep getting the Runtime error '438' when ran. Any advice on how to fix this or if clicking this link is even possible please? Thanks.

**EDIT (Full Code):**

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "site"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set objA = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("website")(0) 'GETTIN ERROR HERE
objA.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you identify at what point in the chain You're getting `Err#438`?  It could be an issue with how you're working with the Document object.

Comment: I have added the full code above and split it slightly to see where the error is occurring. Seems to be when searching for the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that there were a few minor issues here.

One being that `.Click` doesn't always function properly, I would suggest using `.getAttribute("href")` combined with `ie.Navigate()`

Another being that you seem to define html then never use it again.

The following code works:

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://beverlyhills.yourkwoffice.com/mcj/user/AssociateSearchSubmitAction.do?orgId=5058&lastName=&firstName=&rows=100"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.Document

Set objA = html.getElementsByClassName("website")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
ie.Navigate (objA.getAttribute("href"))
End Sub
```